# Нужна ли запятая в следующем заголовке статьи: "Фотосъемка, выведенная на новый уровень"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в следующем заголовке статьи: "Фотосъемка, выведенная на новый уровень"?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, она отделяет причастный оборот.